# How to change the number formatting of certain columns in an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to remove the dollar sign formatting, `$###,##0.00` and replace it with `#,##0.00` number formatting.

I have tried changing the format of just one cell in the sheet, but I have no idea if it is doing anything because nothing is changing in the file.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['example']
sheet('E7').number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

I expected the output to change the value at E7 from **$380.00** to **380.00**, but I am receiving `TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable` and nothing is happening to the file.

Comment: Can you right click the cell, go to `Format Cells` and see if anything changed under Category in the Number tab?

Comment: It is still showing number as `$###,##0.00`

Comment: From a quick look in the source code it doesn't seem like they actually support different numbering formats, but I can't say for sure. Have a look [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html#Cell) and search for number_format

Comment: The error you are getting is because you need to change `sheet('E7')` to `sheet['E7']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For an individual cell:**

```
import re
f_clean = lambda x: re.sub('[$\-,\|]', '', x)
f_float = lambda x: float(x) if x!='' else np.NaN

print(f_float(f_clean('$10,000.00')))
# 10000.0
```

**For an entire column:**

```
# Here's a solution I use for large datasets:

import re

def lookup_money(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to parsing currency to floats.
    For large data, the same currencies are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique values, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all figures.
    (Should be 10X faster than without lookup dict)
    """
    f_clean = lambda x: re.sub('[$\-,\|]', '', x)
    f_float = lambda x: float(x) if x!='' else np.NaN
    currencies = {curr:f_float(f_convert(curr)) for curr in s.unique()}
    return s.map(currencies)

# apply to some df as such:
# df['curr'] = df['curr'].apply(lookup_money)
```

Comment: It works on the number inside the parenthesis of f_clean, but how would I go about applying it to a column in an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @oroy anyway you will have to loop all cells... even if you could change the number_format directly

Comment: _Changing my answer for the column..._

Comment: @YaakovBressler the or operator `|` is not necessary inside a set

Comment: `|` is removed from the string, good for universal cleaning but not necessary per se in this case.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I will try to do that. It shows [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=number%20format) that it is possible to change number_format.

Comment: @YaakovBressler but it appears 3 times indise the set, that's redundant

Comment: AH. That. Yes, that's the `or` operator in regular expressions. (Correct in your labeling it as such.)

Comment: What would be the alternative for that? _(I'm not familiar)_

Comment: In regex, when you use square brackets `[]` they represent a set. The regex will try to match any of the characters inside it (once). So it's already doing "or" between those characters. you would put it there if you wanted to literraly match the `|` character. read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thanks! _I modified my answer._

Comment: The question is about applying a number format in an Excel file. Excel handles how this is displayed.